# Function argument unpacking error

Tags: python, argument-unpacking

Look at this example (using python 2.7.6):

```
>>> def func(a, b, c, d):  
    print a, b, c, d

>>> func(1, c = 3, *(2,), **{'d':4})
1 2 3 4
```

Up to here, this is fine. But, why the following call fails?

```
>>> func(1, b = 3, *(2,), **{'d':4})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
    func(1, b = 3, *(2,), **{'d':4})
TypeError: func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? It matters.

Comment: Python 2.7 does not throw an error.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.6

Comment: That's right. You are providing 2 values for b (a positional and by keyword)

Comment: It's an interesting question, I wonder why would anyone would use it in practice in such oblique manner.

Comment: @JBernardo 1 is the only one positional argument. Right? Where am I providing two values for b?

Comment: @user3022222 See my answer below

Comment: @rdodev you are perfectly right. This is just an example intended to show how far we can go with Python function call. It is for educational purpose. But hitting this issue means that I missed something (or that there is a bug).

Comment: @user3022222 cool. just hoping you weren't going to release software with insane argument passing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be better understood with another function signature

```
>>> def func(*args, **kw):
        print(args, kw)


>>> func(1, b = 3, *(2,), **{'d':4})
(1, 2) {'b': 3, 'd': 4}
```

So, the positional arguments are put together and so are the keyword arguments.

Using the original signature, it means both `2` and `3` will be assigned to `b`, which is not valid.

**PS:** Because a simple tuple unpacking does not provide names, the values will be treated as positional arguments.

Comment: Again, I find this interesting, but by golly I hope people don't use it to pass arguments in such convoluted manner. I wonder if PEP8 has something to say about the way to pass arguments around.

Comment: @JBernardo Your answer makes sense to me, but it is not what I got reading the Python documentation. I understood that during a function call, arguments are processed in the following order: positional, named, *Targ, **Darg. You say (and show) that they are processed in the following order: positional, *Targ, named, **Darg. Do you have at hand the python documentation or PEP describing this behavior?

Comment: @user3022222 No, what I said is that they are eventually put together because `*args` are also positional arguments.

Comment: @JBernardo I believe I start to understand what is going on. Correct me if I am wrong. Arguments in function calls must be in the order: positional, named, *Targs, **Dargs. But positional arguments (real positional and *Targs) are passed first to the function, then all the named arguments (real named ones and **Dargs) are passed. If ever a named argument has already been passed with a positional argument there is an error.

Comment: @JBernardo This is, in my opinion, a strong case against mixing positional and named arguments, because to prevent collisions on argument passing you need to know exactly the function header (thus no need for positional arguments).

Comment: @user3022222 Yes, if you are passing `*args` it's better to not use `key = value` pairs, unless you are sure the names are going to be caught by `**kwargs`